# Country State City in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I try to create a dropdown list for Country State and City , I have 3 separate arrays for `Country`, `State` & `City` respectively.

I'm able to get the elements in the dropdown list but the problem is that I cam not able to make the dropdown dependent on the previous one.

```js
$scope.countrylist = [

  {
    Id: 1,
    CountryName: "India",

  }, {
    Id: 2,
    CountryName: "America"
  }
];

$scope.statelist = [{
    Id: 1,
    StateName: "Maharashtra",
    CountryId: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    StateName: "MadhyaPradesh",
    CountryId: 1
  }, {
    Id: 3,
    StateName: "Washington",
    CountryId: 2
  }
];
$scope.citylist = [{
    Id: 1,
    CityName: "Pune",
    StateId: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    CityName: "Mumbai",
    StateId: 1
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    CityName: "Bhopal",
    StateId: 2
  }
];
```

```html
<div class="row pb-4">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="Country">{{
                'guardian.country' | translate}} :</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country" ng-model="guardian.country" ng-options="country.CountryName as country.CountryName for country in countrylist track by country.CountryName" ng-change="getSelectedCountry()">
                            <option value=''>Select</option>
                          </select>
    <label>{{strCountry}}</label>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="row pb-4">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="State">{{'guardian.state' | translate}} :</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" required id="state" name="state" ng-disabled="!guardian.country" ng-model="guardian.state" ng-options="state.StateName as state.StateName for state in statelist track by state.StateName" ng-change="getSelectedState()">
                            <option value=''>Select</option>
                          </select>
    <label>{{strState}}</label>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row pb-4">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="City">{{
                'guardian.city' | translate}} :</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city" ng-disabled="!guardian.country || !guardian.state" ng-model="guardian.city" ng-options="city.CityName as city.CityName for city in citylist track by city.CityName" ng-change="getSelectedCity()">
                           <option value=''>Select</option>
                           </select>
    <label>{{strCity}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want anyone to complete my task , i just want to know where I am going wrong. A bit of guidance would be appreciated .

Comment: Bro, Please share code so far  you have tried to make dropdown  dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.guardian = {}
  $scope.countrylist = [

    {
      Id: 1,
      CountryName: "India",

    }, {
      Id: 2,
      CountryName: "America"
    }
  ];

  $scope.statelist = [{
      Id: 1,
      StateName: "Maharashtra",
      CountryId: 1
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      StateName: "MadhyaPradesh",
      CountryId: 1
    }, {
      Id: 3,
      StateName: "Washington",
      CountryId: 2
    }
  ];
  $scope.citylist = [{
      Id: 1,
      CityName: "Pune",
      StateId: 1
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      CityName: "Mumbai",
      StateId: 1
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      CityName: "Bhopal",
      StateId: 2
    }
  ];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div class="row pb-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="Country">country :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country" ng-model="guardian.country" ng-options="country as country.CountryName for country in countrylist track by country.CountryName">                             <option value=''>Select</option>
                          </select>
      <label>{{strCountry}}</label>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row pb-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="State">state :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select class="form-control" required id="state" name="state" ng-disabled="!guardian.country" ng-model="guardian.state" ng-options="state as state.StateName for state in statelist | filter:{CountryId:guardian.country.Id} track by state.StateName ">
                            <option value=''>Select</option>
                          </select>
      <label>{{strState}}</label>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row pb-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="City">city :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city" ng-disabled="!guardian.country || !guardian.state" ng-model="guardian.city" ng-options="city as city.CityName for city in citylist | filter:{StateId:guardian.state.Id} track by city.CityName">
                           <option value=''>Select</option>
                           </select>
      <label>{{strCity}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. But spoon feeding is wrong. OP need to understand it. Also lots of similar answer available .